# Drupal theme error. functions from add on libraries are not included when running my custom script

Tags: theming, javascript

I'm trying to load a javascript function in my custom script with jquery and materialize. When the script load it says

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function and sidenav() is not defined.
```

My theme library is as follows

```
    global-styling:
  version: VERSION
  css:
    base:
      materialize/css/materialize.min.css: {}
      css/style.css: {}
  js:
    materialize/js/materialize.min.js: { minified:true}
    js/layout.js: {}
  dependencies:
    - core/jquery
```

My layout.js is simple

```
  $('.sidenav').sidenav();
```

If I look at dev tools it shows materialize and jquery loading before my script. I followed the answer to get jquery working but sidenav() comes back undefined. sidenav() is a materialize function and material.js is loading before this script.

How do I properly attach a 3rd party js framework and call a function from it?

Answer (score 1):

$ is a shortcode for jQuery, does your layout.js contain just

```
 $('.sidenav').sidenav();
```

Maybe try

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
 })(jQuery, Drupal);
```

You can read more here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview

Comment: That seemed to work to fix jquery. It won't, however, read .sidenav() which is a materialize function. I'm guessing I'm going need to somehow include materialize.js in the ($, Drupal) part?